# Best way to format SQL output to a JSON?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2017

Been trying to take a SQL query and output the perfect JSON but I'm running into issues.  The query merely involves to tables, when I use "For JSON Auto" it produces a flat array of objects: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q72MP.png)

However there is a hierarchical relationship:

Q2CNum---
LineItems----
Identifier

I've attempted to use "For JSON Path" but it only structures each json object (it won't aggregate all Identifiers under their parent LineItem for example).

I've managed to get it to look like this by joining the table to itself (same query just extra joins, the "For JSON Path Auto" seems to like this) and it looks more like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeBkY.png)

Which is good. Problem is the query takes almost 20 times as long (2seconds vs 20).

Perhaps my self joins are badly written, or joining to get these results is inefficient.

Anyway if anyone has a clue how to do this let me know (can't share too much more, I'm sure you noticed the color blockout on the images).

UPDATE:

Here's pic of the query [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOXe3.png).  The problem is I get a flat JSON (just an array of object).

```
Select OWS.Q2CNum, 
       OWS.LineItem, 
       OWS.Identifier, 
       OWS.ProductType, 
       OWS.Workstation, 
       OWS.Calculation, 
       OWS.UnitOfMeasure, 
       OWS.CurrentStatus, 
       LS.Location, 
       LS.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
FROM table1 AS OWS
INNER JOIN table2 AS LS
ON OWS.Q2CNum = LS.[Order]
AND OWS.LineItem = LS.LineItem
AND OWS.Identifier = LS.Identifier
WHERE LS.ProgramStamp_LocalTime = 
    (Select TOP 1 LS2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
    from dbo.view_Location_Stamps_Local AS LS2 
    Where LS2.[Order] = OWS.Q2CNum
    AND LS2.LineItem= OWS.LineItem
    AND LS2.Identifier = OWS.Identifier
    Order by LS2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime Desc) 
AND LS.[Order] = @testVar
AND LS.LineItem = COALESCE('001',OWS.LineItem)
AND LS.Identifier like '%'
---Group by Q2CNum
ORDER BY Q2CNum, LineItem, Identifier DESC
FOR JSON Auto
```

But I need it to be hierarchal:

```
{
    Q2CNum: value,
    LineItems: [{
         LineItem: value,
         Identifiers: [{
               identifier: value,
               etc...
         }],
    }],

}
```

Update 2:

If I run this query I get more of what I want:

```
Select Q2C.Q2CNum, 
       Li.LineItem  , 
       OWS.Identifier, 
       OWS.ProductType, 
       OWS.Workstation, 
       OWS.Calculation, 
       OWS.UnitOfMeasure, 
       OWS.CurrentStatus, 
       LS.Location, 
       LS.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
FROM table1 AS OWS
INNER JOIN table2 AS Q2C
ON Q2C.Q2CNum = OWS.Q2CNum and Q2C.LineItem = OWS.LineItem and Q2C.Identifier = OWS.Identifier and Q2C.Workstation = OWS.Workstation
INNER JOIN table3 AS Li
ON Li.Q2CNum = OWS.Q2CNum and Li.LineItem = OWS.LineItem and Li.Identifier = OWS.Identifier and Li.Workstation = OWS.Workstation
INNER JOIN table4 AS LS
ON OWS.Q2CNum = LS.[Order]
AND OWS.LineItem = LS.LineItem
AND OWS.Identifier = LS.Identifier
WHERE LS.ProgramStamp_LocalTime = 
    (Select TOP 1 LS2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
    from table5 AS LS2 
    Where LS2.[Order] = OWS.Q2CNum
    AND LS2.LineItem= OWS.LineItem
    AND LS2.Identifier = OWS.Identifier
    Order by LS2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime Desc) 
AND LS.[Order] = @testVar
AND LS.LineItem = COALESCE('001',OWS.LineItem)
AND LS.Identifier like '%'
---Group by Q2CNum
ORDER BY Q2CNum, LineItem, Identifier DESC
FOR JSON Auto
```

But the time for the query takes longer.

***Final Update:***

Ok so Mike Petri's solution works.  I had to tinker with it and try to wrap my head around it (still doing that- I was a lot more confident in my SQL skills before this). In any case here is the final code I used (the top half doesn't really matter, I had written that query, the only importance there is using a temp table.  I'd use a view BUT I have resource restrictions so this is better atm).  The real magic begins at the bottom half of the Query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Temp;
END;

SELECT  OWS.Q2CNum
        ,OWS.LineItem
        ,OWS.Identifier
        ,OWS.ProductType
        ,OWS.Workstation
        ,OWS.Calculation
        ,OWS.UnitOfMeasure
        ,OWS.CurrentStatus
        ,LS.Location
        ,LS.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
INTO    #Temp
FROM    table1 AS OWS
        INNER JOIN table2 AS LS ON OWS.Q2CNum = LS.[Order]
                                   AND OWS.LineItem = LS.LineItem
                                   AND OWS.Identifier = LS.Identifier
WHERE   LS.ProgramStamp_LocalTime = (
                                        SELECT  TOP 1
                                                LS2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
                                        FROM    talbe3 AS LS2
                                        WHERE   LS2.[Order] = OWS.Q2CNum
                                                AND LS2.LineItem = OWS.LineItem
                                                AND LS2.Identifier = OWS.Identifier
                                        ORDER BY
                                                LS2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime DESC
                                    )
        AND LS.[Order] = @testVar
        AND LS.LineItem = COALESCE('001', OWS.LineItem)
        AND LS.Identifier LIKE '%';

----REAL MAGIC HAPPENS HERE

SELECT t.Q2CNum
        ,(
             SELECT DISTINCT(t2.LineItem)
                    ,(
                         SELECT  DISTINCT(t3.Identifier)
                                ,t3.Location
                                ,t3.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
                                ,(
                                    SELECT   t4.Workstation
                                            ,t4.ProductType
                                            ,t4.Calculation
                                            ,t4.UnitOfMeasure
                                            ,t4.CurrentStatus
                                    FROM #Temp AS t4
                                    WHERE t3.Q2CNum = t4.Q2CNum and t3.LineItem = t4.LineItem and  t3.Identifier = t4.Identifier
                                    FOR JSON PATH 
                                ) AS Workstations
                        FROM #Temp AS t3
                        WHERE t3.Q2CNum = t2.Q2CNum and t2.LineItem = t3.LineItem
                        FOR JSON PATH
                     ) AS Identifiers
             FROM   #Temp AS t2
             WHERE  t.Q2CNum = t2.Q2CNum
             FOR JSON PATH
         ) AS LineItems
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    Q2CNum
            FROM    #Temp
        ) AS t
FOR JSON AUTO;
DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

All criticism welcome (one thing I'm wondering is the proper way to filter (with the Where clause) the concentric SQL selects i.e. should table t4 just filter to table t3 (it's immediate Hierarchal parent?) or should I also add constraints to t4 and t2?  Or t4 and t?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and JSON support is highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: not sure what DBMS u'r using but why not just do the merge in code instead of query?

Comment: No clue which DBMS i'm using (googled how to find it but suggestions aren't working).
Right now I'm using the "For JSON AUTO" or "FOR JSON PATH" at the end of the SQL query to create the JSON.

I realized I could probably manipulate the JSON within the application (that's receiving the data) but it seems better to do it here (that way where ever I send it, it will be in a consistent form).

Comment: Please post the SQL Query you're working with (not an image). DBMS means which server platform you are working with. SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Sorry I can't post the actual code, might get in trouble with the company. I understand what DBMS means, just no clue how to check it, regardless SQL has functionality to create JSON.

I'm trying to use that functionality right now but it's super finicky.  I have a fairly simple query joining two tables but to get the data aggregated correctly in a JSON I have to join one of the tables several times on itself.  When I do this once it adds one second to the query, twice it adds 20 seconds.

I just figured we certainly had the capability of converting SQL to JSON from SQL .

Comment: Well, if you can't post your query, or even a sanitized version (e.g. replacing column names with something arbitrary), not sure how to help here. I've done tons of JSON queries, and it's pretty straightforward. Regarding your DBMS, if you execute SELECT @@VERSION, what comes back?

Comment: Query is in original post, my version is Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: Meant I added the SQL code, changed table names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this gets you closer.
Being that you have joins involved, referencing inner/outer queries gets dicey. You could either make the base query a VIEW, and replace the #Temp references, or use the code below to store it in a temp table, then reference the outer table by the inner one to get the groupings you're after.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Temp;
END;

SELECT  OWS.Q2CNum
        ,OWS.LineItem
        ,OWS.Identifier
        ,OWS.ProductType
        ,OWS.Workstation
        ,OWS.Calculation
        ,OWS.UnitOfMeasure
        ,OWS.CurrentStatus
        ,LS.Location
        ,LS.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
INTO    #Temp
FROM    table1 AS OWS
        INNER JOIN table2 AS LS ON OWS.Q2CNum = LS.[Order]
                                   AND OWS.LineItem = LS.LineItem
                                   AND OWS.Identifier = LS.Identifier
WHERE   LS.ProgramStamp_LocalTime = (
                                        SELECT  TOP 1
                                                LS2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
                                        FROM    dbo.view_Location_Stamps_Local AS LS2
                                        WHERE   LS2.[Order] = OWS.Q2CNum
                                                AND LS2.LineItem = OWS.LineItem
                                                AND LS2.Identifier = OWS.Identifier
                                        ORDER BY
                                                LS2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime DESC
                                    )
        AND LS.[Order] = @testVar
        AND LS.LineItem = COALESCE('001', OWS.LineItem)
        AND LS.Identifier LIKE '%';

SELECT  t.Q2CNum
        ,(
             SELECT t2.LineItem
                    ,(
                         SELECT t2.Identifier AS value
                                ,t2.ProductType
                                ,t2.Workstation
                                ,t2.Calculation
                                ,t2.UnitOfMeasure
                                ,t2.CurrentStatus
                                ,t2.Location
                                ,t2.ProgramStamp_LocalTime
                         FOR JSON PATH
                     ) AS Identifiers
             FROM   #Temp AS t2
             WHERE  t.Q2CNum = t2.Q2CNum
             FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
         ) AS LineItems
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    Q2CNum
            FROM    #Temp
        ) AS t
FOR JSON AUTO;

DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

Comment: Oh wow that was close, and fast.  It failed to aggregate everything under Q2CNum but thanks for this, will try to reverse engineer it

Comment: Right on! If you found the answer helpful, please mark as the answer by clicking the check :-D

Comment: Hmmm I don't think this ultimately solves it.  It's structuring a JSON nicely, but it's doing it for every single SQL row/entry.  My fundamental issue is there is a heiarchical relationship within the query (Q2CNum => LineItem => Identifier).

I think I'll have to do a recursive query maybe. Or it's impossible lol.  Either way I clicked the check

Comment: I see. I've updated the code. See if that gets you farther down the road

Comment: Dude you're a godsend. Think I got it working, will post final solution.  Is there a word for the Select statements your utilizing? (something I can google next time? I know what a Subselect is but you're utilizing it to Subselect Columns, or rather sub-attributes of columns.)

I guess what I'm asking is there terminology for any of this? i'm decent with SQL but haven't seen stuff like this (is it specific to formatting JSON?).

Comment: In any case, can't thank you enough, started new software job and spent literally all day on this.  I'd upvote your solution but i don't have reputation.

Comment: One last question if you get time: what is the proper way to filter (with the Where clause) the concentric SQL selects i.e. should table t4 just filter to table t3 (it's immediate Hierarchal parent?) or should I also add constraints to t4 and t2?  Or t4 and t?

Comment: It's just a subselect, or subquery, or nested select. Think of it like this; it's just a data object within your query. You can have tables, views , functions, whatever; or a SQL statement you wrap in parenthesis. All of these can interact with other data objects in the query (e.g. join, filter, etc). As far as your WHERE clause question, I believe you should be able to do away with the t4 reference altogether, only using t3 columns, as you should already filtered to that level. Basically, your Workstations node would be comprised of t3 columns, still wrapped in parenthesis; just no t4 table.

Comment: But then, there may be more going on in your data that is apparent. If you need that t4 reference, it doesn't look incorrect, but I'd try to reduce the table usage if possible. If the data already exists in the stream, snag it; no need to tie it in again if it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use "FOR JSON PATH" for List
and "FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER" for Item